# pip install nnsplit is not working, how to fix it?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

[nnsplit](https://bminixhofer.github.io/nnsplit/) looks promising and I'd like to start using it on my PC, but I'm getting the following error when I run `pip install nnsplit`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nnsplit (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nnsplit
```

I'm using windows 11 and I've tried to install it on Python 3.10.9 and Python 3.11 with no luck

Comment: Looking at the PyPI page, the listed versions are provided for Python >=3.6,<4.0, but have all been [yanked](https://pypi.org/help/#yanked). The later releases of that package have been published only as wheels (no source distributions), and only for Python 3.5-3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try Python 3.9
I had the same issue when installing it with Python 3.10. After downgrading python to 3.9, it worked